# Deserialize iso 8601 date

Tags: c#, json, datetime, json.net, iso8601

I have a class as following:

```
public class ViewItem
{
    [DataMember(Name = "title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "created_at")]
    public string CreatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to deserialize json string to object, I never get value for `CreatedAt` field. My json string is as follows:

```
[ { "created_at" : "2014-03-05T10:26:12Z" ,
    "title"      : "task 4"
  } ,
  { "created_at" : "2014-03-05T10:26:12Z" ,
    "title"      : "task 5"
  }
]
```

The deserialization code is as follows:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ViewItem>>(json);
```

I have read [this article](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/02/20/good-date-times-with-json-net) and tried to supply different json convert as well date parse handling but it did not work.

**Update:**

I have tried CreatedAt property as DateTime, DateTime? and DateTimeOffset as well as simple string.

Comment: Your JSON is invalid.  There needs to be a comma between the date value and the `title` property.  You can check it at [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: Thanks. Actually it is typo mistake as I copy paste from Visual Studio IDE to here. I corrected it though. But still it does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `[DataContract]` to your class declaration.  Also change the type of the `CreatedAt` property from `string` to `DateTime`:

```
[DataContract]
public class ViewItem
{
    [DataMember(Name = "title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "created_at")]
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

With these changes (and the fix to the JSON), it works for me:

```
string json = @"[{""created_at"":""2014-03-05T10:26:12Z"",""title"":""task 4""},{""created_at"":""2014-03-05T10:26:12Z"",""title"":""task 5""}]";

List<ViewItem> list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ViewItem>>(json);
foreach (ViewItem item in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Title: " + item.Title);
    Console.WriteLine("CreatedAt: " + item.CreatedAt);
}
```

Output:

```
Title: task 4
CreatedAt: 3/5/2014 10:26:12 AM
Title: task 5
CreatedAt: 3/5/2014 10:26:12 AM
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `DataMemberAttribute` which is from `System.Runtime.Serialization`. but `JsonConvert` from `Newtonsoft.Json` to deserialize.

Use:

```
[JsonProperty("title")]
```

Instead of:

```
[DataMember(Name = "title")]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime dateProperty=Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime)
```

will yield

> "dateProperty":"/Date(1343966400000-0400)/"

Whereas:

```
string dateProperty=Convert.ToString(DateTime)
```

will yield

> "dateProperty":"8/3/2012 6:20:43 PM"